# Add Comma to string in Calculator while user is typing a number like (1000) formatted to (1,000)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on a Calculator just for fun, so I have been trying to make the behaviour as similar as possible as the iOS7 Calculator. Now, I have encounter a problem, when the user is inputting a number in the calculator, I'm using **`stringByAppendingString`** to add each number the user press.

So, I already came up with a way to format the result of a calculation using **`NSNumberFormatter`** to display the comma if the result of this is for example `1000 = 1,000`. But, it has been a bit more difficult to do it to my **`UILabel Screen`** to update the current string that the user is typing at the moment. Which it will happen as soon as the user inputs a number like `2000 = 2,000`.

Just, to explain it a bit better for the case above the user types 2 and it will be sent to the Screen. Then, 0 it will be Append with **`stringByAppendingString`** and sent to the **`Screen`** and so on..

So, I have been trying to modify my function appendDigit to try to handle this case in my calculator in this way,

```
- (void)appendDigit:(NSString *)digit {

    screenF = [[self screenValue] floatValue];
    NSString *display = [NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber:@(screenF)                                                             numberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

    if ([self.Screen.text isEqualToString:@"0"] && ![digit isEqualToString:@"."]) {
        self.Screen.text = digit;
    } else if(self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEntereingANumber){
        self.Screen.text = digit;
        self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEntereingANumber = NO;
    } else{
        display = [Screen.text stringByAppendingString:digit];
        self.Screen.text = display;
    }

}
```

**UPDATED** version of **appendDigit**,

```
- (void)appendDigit:(NSString *)digit {

    if ([self.Screen.text isEqualToString:@"0"] && ![digit isEqualToString:@"."]) {
        self.Screen.text = digit;
    } else if(self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEntereingANumber){
        self.Screen.text = digit;
        self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEntereingANumber = NO;
    } else{
        self.Screen.text = [Screen.text stringByAppendingString:digit];

        float screenTmp = [[self screenValue] floatValue];

        NSString *display = [NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber:@(screenTmp) numberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
        self.Screen.text = display;

    }
}
```

This is my function to get a float value from the **`Screen`** which, I usually use for my calculation but, I was trying to use it to get the current number that the user has input it so far,

```
- (NSNumber *)screenValue {
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormat = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    numberFormat.usesGroupingSeparator = YES;
    numberFormat.groupingSeparator = @",";
    numberFormat.groupingSize = 3;
    [numberFormat setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    return [numberFormat numberFromString:self.Screen.text];
}
```

This is an example of one of the button (digit/number) in my calculator,

```
-(IBAction)Number8:(UIButton *)sender{
    [self appendDigit:@"8"];
}

-(IBAction)Number9:(UIButton *)sender{
    [self appendDigit:@"9"];
}
```

This is how I'm doing the formatting to add the comma to the calculation results,

```
-(IBAction)Equals:(UIButton *)sender{

    [self MyOperations];

    NSString *display = [NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber:@(result)                                                             numberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    self.Screen.text = display;

    self.Method = 0;

    self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEntereingANumber = NO;
}
```

Well, I hope someone could guide through this and give my hand to over the problem. If you guys need more information or any other part of code that may help to understand things better and get to a solution, please let me know and I will be happy to add it to the post. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of appending each digit user is typing, set a whole string. Keep a reference to a typed number. For example:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *number;
```

Every time user types a number, combine it with a number. Then, convert it to a string just before you place it in a label using `NSNumberFormatter`.

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormat = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
numberFormat.usesGroupingSeparator = YES;
numberFormat.groupingSeparator = @",";
numberFormat.groupingSize = 3;
```

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try to do this and get back to you. Thanks for the answer, I'm in Objective-C so, probably I will come back with some questions..

Comment: How will you convert it? I'm calling my screenValue function.. screenF = [[self screenValue] floatValue]; then, I am doing this within my appendDigit function screenF = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g%@", screenF, digit] intValue]; but, is not working.. I have updated my screenValue function with the information you provide..

Comment: @NorthBlast if you have an `NSNumberFormatter` applied to the `UILabel` all you have to do is update the label with the raw number and it will be automagically formatted with whatever format you gave the formatter. Dont bother trying to manage any strings for displaying anything.

Comment: that's what I tried but I don't why its not working.. @BradAllred

Comment: @BradAllred, to the best of my knowledge you can't attach number formatters to views in iOS like you can in Mac OS. You have to take the number, convert it to a string using the number formatter's stringFromNumber method, then install the string into the label manually. This was an adjustment for me when I moved from Mac OS to iOS.

Comment: @DuncanC Oh wow, I didnt realize that. Wonder why not, since it is so convenient.

Comment: Hey guys, I came up with a new version of the appendDigit function and works only until it reaches (for example 1,000) then it resets the number to 0. It doesn't keep adding numbers to the screen..